# Cannot read property 'datepickerLocale' of undefined

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, bootstrap-datetimepicker

This may be a specific issue but I am stuck after quite some debugging done. Maybe a fresh pair of eyes would see something I am missing. I have posted only the relevant code snippets, as it is a bigger app.

Everything works fine, however I keep getting this error and I don't exactly know what would be causing it and how it could affect the code.

```
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
       header: {
           left: 'prev,next today',
           center: 'title',
           right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
       },
       defaultView: 'agendaDay',
       defaultTimedEventDuration: '00:10:00',
       locale: 'ro',
       timeFormat:'H:mm',
       slotLabelFormat:"HH:mm",
       axisFormat: 'H:mm',        
       navLinks: true,
       selectable: true,
       selectHelper: true,
       allDaySlot: false,
       eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
           editEvent(calEvent);
       },
       eventLimit: true // allow "more" link when too many events

   });

  console.log('The right one');
   $("#starts-at").datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    locale: 'ro'
   });

  $("#starts-at-edited").datetimepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    locale: 'ro'
  }); 

<script src='vendor/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='vendor/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
<script src='vendor/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='vendor/fullcalendar.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/4.17.47/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script> 
<script src='vendor/locale/ro.js'></script>
<script src='calendar.js'></script>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you add the section of html? It's very hard to understand where and how all this snippets fit together. Maybe a plunkr will help?